# Need CLI ssh server for windows

Tags: windows, ssh, command-line-interface

I am searching for as small as possible console-based ssh server for windows machines. I just need to make one server capable of tunneling so i wouldn't really need ssh keys or anything, just a simple and small ssh server application.

What are your advices ?

Answer (score 1):

I am useing [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org) via [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). An actively maintened package that combines those two would be [copssh](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) (got this from http://www.openssh.org/windows.html and am using it to securely transfer files via scp off a windows host)

Answer (score 0):

How about http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/